# Batch printing mvc cshtml forms with query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to batch print mvc3 cshtml forms based on a url with parameters. For instance, I would like to iterate through urls something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<10: i++) 
    print(http://mysite/myController/myAction/i);
```

or are there more preferred techniques to achieve this goal.

Comment: Where do you want to print? On the server? On the client?

Comment: HI Darin - This would be printed from the client. For example, from a "parent" form, the user would select a "Print All" button.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the following project and add your code that will loop through your pages:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12799/Print-HTML-in-C-with-or-without-the-web-browser-co